# Express with EJS - Render a function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to render a function call in express with EJS?

Currently tried:

```
res.render("page", {
   test: test()
});
```

Anyone can confirm this is possible or somehow can show, how to call a function from front-end (Public-folder), on page-render?

Please, only show examples in vanilla-JS, not jQuery.

To clarify a little more. I have a Js-file in my public folder, with a function, eg. `./public/js/file.js` - with a function called: `test()`;

Can I somehow in express with EJS, render the page with a call on `test();`?

Comment: Can you please provide more context? What does `file.js` and specifically `test()` do? I'm skeptical that it's possible, but I may be wrong. From the docs, the 2nd argument to res.render is an object whose properties define local variables for the view (the view being the 1st argument).

Comment: The `file.js` could contain any function, eg. a simple `console.log("Hello")`, it's currently only for testing purpose.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your end goal is, but if I've understood correctly, you ought to be able to achieve what you're trying to do via middleware. Something like `app.use('page', function (req, res, next) { console.log('Request Type:', req.method); next(); })`. The function is executed for any type of HTTP request on the `page` path.

Comment: Yes, but file.js cannot be clientside js, it should be available from server side js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that it is not possible to call a function from frontend in the backend's render function as a callback.